# MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification isn't called

Tags: iphone, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm converting my iOS3 app to iOS4 and having problems with the movie player! I have followed [the example here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html) (I don't need it to work in iOS3 anymore!) and subclassed UIViewController with the following code:

```
#import "moviePlayer.h"

@implementation moviePlayer
@synthesize mainAppDelegate;
@synthesize mp;

- (id)initWithMovie:(NSString *)moviePath delegate:(id)delegate {
    self.mainAppDelegate = delegate;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:mainAppDelegate selector:@selector(movieFinishedPlaying:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    self.mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
    [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [mp setShouldAutoplay:YES];

    return self;
}

- (void) moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSLog(@"moviePlayerLoadStateChanged");

    // Unless state is unknown, start playback
    if ([mp loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) {

        // Remove observer
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

        //Set Landscape and Rotate
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
        [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
        [[self view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
        [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];

        //Set frame, add view and play
        [[mp view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
        [[self view] addSubview:[mp view]];
        [mp play];

        //Tell main app that it worked!
        [mainAppDelegate performSelector:@selector(movieLoaded:) withObject:mp];

    } else if ([mp loadState] == MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
        [mainAppDelegate performSelector:@selector(movieLoaded:) withObject:nil];
    }

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [mainAppDelegate release];
    [mp release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

`moviePath` is a local file that has been downloaded and saved onto the device.

The problem is that `moviePlayerLoadStateChanged` doesn't get called sometimes.  If the file is downloaded then played from the device it works everytime, if I try to play the file from its saved location it doesn't get called - I can hear the movie sound, but can't see it as there is no view for it to play in!

I've used `NSLog(@"%@", moviePath);` at the top of init to see the difference and there is none - the URL (local path) is the same whichever?!

Comment: If you provide a link, also provide context. If that link breaks, so does the context of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but Google brought me here while looking something else up.  Since there isn't an answer, and someone else might be wondering,

`MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`

Is specifically called ONLY during network fetches.  As per Apple's documentation:

> Posted when a movie player’s network buffering state has changed. There is no userInfo dictionary.
>
> To retrieve the current load state of a movie player, access its loadState property. The movie player whose state has changed is available as the object associated with the notification.

As such, the OP's problem, that of the notification only firing when the file in question is downloaded, is functioning as intended by Apple.